# I am unable to use @use when compiling through 11ty's method

Tags: sass

Recently, I tried using the new SASS compilation method outlined in 11ty's article 'Minimum Static Site Setup with Sass', with a **package.json** file that looks like this:

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "SASS compile|autoprefix|minimize and live-reload dev server using Browsersync for static HTML",
  "main": "public/index.html",
  "author": "5t3ph",
  "scripts": {
    "build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/sass:public/css",
    "copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/*.html public",
    "copy": "npm-run-all --parallel copy:*",
    "watch:html": "onchange 'src/*.html' -- npm run copy:html",
    "watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/sass:public/css",
    "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "serve": "browser-sync start --server public --files public",
    "start": "npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
    "build": "npm-run-all copy:html build:*",
    "postbuild": "postcss public/css/*.css -u autoprefixer cssnano -r --no-map"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.17",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.8"
  }
}
```

// ./helpers/_variables.scss

```
//* GRADIENT COLOR */
$--gradient-1: linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(270, 5%, 7%, 0) 0%, hsla(270, 5%, 7%, 0.8) 65%, hsl(270, 5%, 7%) 100%);
$--gradient-2: linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(260, 5%, 12%, 0) 0%, hsla(260, 5%, 12%, 0.8) 65%, hsl(260, 5%, 12%) 100%);

//* TYPOGRAPHY */
$--ff-nunito-sans: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
```

// ./base/_reset.scss

```
@use '../helpers/variables' as *;
html {
    font-family: $--ff-nunito-sans;
    font-size: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    background-color: $--background;
    color: $--on-background;
    font-size: $--body-3;
    overflow: hidden;
    // height: 300vh;
}
```

// ./_index.scss

```
@forward './base/reset';
@forward './helpers/variables';
```

// ./style.scss

```
@use '../sass' as *;
```

However, I received an error message:

[Browsersync] File event [change]: public\css\style.css

Error: Undefined variable.

╷
57 │ font-family: $--ff-nunito-sans;
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

src\sass\base_reset.scss 57:18 @forward

src\sass_index.scss 1:1 @use

src\sass\style.scss 1:1 root stylesheet.

I initially thought that the issue might be due to an outdated version of SASS installed through the package.json file using npm. So, I tried updating to the latest version of SASS and checked that it was compiled with dart2js 2.19.2, but I still couldn't use @use as intended. Is there something else that could be causing the problem?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to import your variables with `@use '../helpers/variables' as variables`. And then use  `font-family: variables.$-ff-nunito-sans` ?

Comment: I have tried these solutions, but now I'm getting the error message `'Error: Private members can't be accessed from outside their modules.
╷
57 │ font-family: variables.$--ff-nunito-sans;'.`

this even worse